# Ajax requests, database and security

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

This post is more a `question` than an actual `issue` with code.
So for a long time when I had to display for example a list of items from `database`, I used to display the `Id` (`primary key` in the table) directly in the `HTML` like this for example :

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

So like this when I wanted to do an `Ajax` request of the current `clicked` item, it was easy because I just had to retrieve the `attribute` from the `html` like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Item/'+$(this).attr('id'),
    type: 'GET',
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

That's only after browsing a lot of websites that I noticed that nobody display the `primary key` (Id) directly in the `HTML`. But somehow they could still do `ajax` request to the `API` using the `Id` of the clicked `item`. So my question is : How can I get the current clicked `Id` to do my `ajax` request without displaying anywhere. I mean how does these websites manage to do that ? Maybe they get `list` from `server` that they use in the `client` then ? But it still does not explain how they manage to get the `current` clicked `Id`.

Appreciate your thoughts and suggestions on this.

Example of website : https://www.toneden.io/
The chat at the bottom right when connected see `network` and web browser `console`.

Comment: Without an example, its really hard to figure out which website does what, and how?

Comment: @Manikiran See my updated question (at the bottom, you need to have an account though)

Comment: Its being sent, but since the javascripts are minified, you are not able to figure it out easily.

Comment: Do you have another site as an example?

Answer (score 0):

To get response from the server, you have to request something. In this case, you are saying i don't want to display `primary key` anyware in html side and get result from server. my suggestion on this, **In php** > you can use binary number instead of primary key and convert back to number and use acc. to requirements. Example :- decbin() and bindec()

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with displaying an id. I've appended the database id such as `id="game_1281"` in cases where I only want to refer to the DOM in response to a server push update. Another option is to use a data attribute like so: `data-id="1281"`. This allows you to get the value without any messy parsing before sending it to the server.

Referencing a unique id is not a security issue. Just make sure you are doing the appropriate server-side checks to ensure that the action taken is possible for that user based on various constraints and privileges.

Comment: But is it possible to make the id invisible in the HTML. I mean I can click on the div without seeing the id attrribute if I inspect the element.